# set focus on custom validator

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 2 textbox, one for login another for password.
I have 1 custom server side validator too, if password is entered wrong, validator is fired.
What I want is to set focus on this error message.

I have tried `focus()`, and `setfocusonerror` property too. but its not working.

here is my code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator  ID="cvLogin" 
                      runat="server" 
                      Display="Dynamic" 
                      CssClass="login-req"   
                      OnServerValidate="cvLogin_ServerValidate" 
                      ValidationGroup="tovalidate" 
                      SetFocusOnError="True">  
 </asp:CustomValidator>





 protected void cvLogin_ServerValidate(object source,
 ServerValidateEventArgs args)
         {  
if (currentUser == null)
                {
                  args.IsValid = false;
                     MessageBox1.Focus();
                     MessageBox1.SetMessage(Resources.RSResource.Login_InvalidLogin,
 Constants.MessageType.Error);

                 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e04ah0f4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method of `Page`:

```
if (currentUser == null)
{
      args.IsValid = false;
      Page.SetFocus(MessageBox1);
      ...
}
```

I am not sure. But may be you need to place your control on a `Panel`.

**UPDATE 2:**

I checked `SetFocus` method. It works for `TextBoxes`, but doesn't work for `Labels` or `Validators`. So if you want to set focus on message the best choise is using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('MessageBox1').scrollIntoView(true);
```

I also tested this server side code. It works fine:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FocusScript", "document.getElementById('MessageBox1').scrollIntoView(true);", true);
```

Comment: ok.is there any method to put focus on the bottom of page. since my message is displaying at the bottom